Retreiving ValueError: invalid literal for int()
I am retrieving below error I am passing a sample input to the regressor model for prediction but retreiving error. I have tried different ways to fix this but it's not working. Thank you for your help.
#'time' column to Unix timestamp
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).astype(int) // 10**9
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['vehicle_id'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['vehicle_id'])  
X = df[['time', 'vehicle_id', 'vehicle_lat', 'vehicle_lon', 'cell_lat', 'cell_lon']]  # Features
y = df.groupby(['time', 'vehicle_id'])['cell_id'].nunique().reset_index(name='cell_id_count')
df_merged = pd.merge(df, y, on=['time', 'vehicle_id'])

y = df_merged['cell_id_count']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
rf_regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)
rf_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf_regressor.predict(X_test)


#input
vehicle_id = 'veh2312'
time_step = 2194

#filter DataFrame based on 'vehicle_id' and 'time'
sample_input = df[(df['vehicle_id'] == label_encoder.transform([vehicle_id])[0]) & (df['time'] == time_step)]

if len(sample_input) > 0:
    sample_features = sample_input[['time', 'vehicle_id', 'vehicle_lat', 'vehicle_lon', 'cell_lat', 'cell_lon']]
    
    sample_predictions = rf_regressor.predict(sample_features)
    
    print(f"Predicted number of cell_ids for vehicle '{vehicle_id}' at time step {time_step}: {sample_predictions[0]:.0f}")
else:
    print(f"No data found for vehicle '{vehicle_id}' at time step {time_step}.")

Error
---> 47 sample_input = df[(df['vehicle_id'] == label_encoder.transform([vehicle_id])[0]) & (df['time'] == time_step)]
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in astype(self, x, dtype, copy, casting)
     66     def astype(self, x, dtype, *, copy=True, casting="unsafe"):
     67         # astype is not defined in the top level NumPy namespace
---> 68         return x.astype(dtype, copy=copy, casting=casting
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'veh2312'

Sample dataset
cell_id cell_lat    cell_lon    time    vehicle_lat vehicle_lon vehicle_id  distance
2665    43.720118   10.422051   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 1205
2682    43.695238   10.433212   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 1787
20020711    43.716044   10.430057   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 791
27025350    43.710199   10.4247325  2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 167
118817885   43.712409   10.424214   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 349
118825175   43.706199   10.431691   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 731
118840263   43.706233   10.432086   2194    43.70994621 10.42621903 veh2312 766


Does this answer your question? ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

You have veh at the beginning of the vehicle ID. That's not a valid number. You should remove the prefix first, then convert it to an integer.

You need to transform the vehicle_id to int using LabelEncoder and the use the transformed integer value when filtering the df. THis is because the vehicle_id column in your dataframe contains string values, while the label encoder transforms these into integer values. Therefore, the transformed integer values of vehicle_id and the original string values are not directly comparable.
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = {
    'cell_id': [2665, 2682, 20020711, 27025350, 118817885, 118825175, 118840263],
    'cell_lat': [43.720118, 43.695238, 43.716044, 43.710199, 43.712409, 43.706199, 43.706233],
    'cell_lon': [10.422051, 10.433212, 10.430057, 10.4247325, 10.424214, 10.431691, 10.432086],
    'time': [2194, 2194, 2194, 2194, 2194, 2194, 2194],
    'vehicle_lat': [43.70994621, 43.70994621, 43.70994621, 43.70994621, 43.70994621, 43.70994621, 43.70994621],
    'vehicle_lon': [10.42621903, 10.42621903, 10.42621903, 10.42621903, 10.42621903, 10.42621903, 10.42621903],
    'vehicle_id': ['veh2312', 'veh2312', 'veh2312', 'veh2312', 'veh2312', 'veh2312', 'veh2312'],
    'distance': [1205, 1787, 791, 167, 349, 731, 766]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').astype('int64') // 10**9

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['vehicle_id'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['vehicle_id'])

X = df[['time', 'vehicle_id', 'vehicle_lat', 'vehicle_lon', 'cell_lat', 'cell_lon']]
y = df.groupby(['time', 'vehicle_id'])['cell_id'].nunique().reset_index(name='cell_id_count')
df_merged = pd.merge(df, y, on=['time', 'vehicle_id'])

y = df_merged['cell_id_count']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

rf_regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)
rf_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

vehicle_id = 'veh2312'
time_step = 2194

vehicle_id_int = label_encoder.transform([vehicle_id])[0]

sample_input = df[(df['vehicle_id'] == vehicle_id_int) & (df['time'] == time_step)]

if len(sample_input) > 0:
    sample_features = sample_input[['time', 'vehicle_id', 'vehicle_lat', 'vehicle_lon', 'cell_lat', 'cell_lon']]
    sample_predictions = rf_regressor.predict(sample_features)
    print(f"Predicted number of cell_ids for vehicle '{vehicle_id}' at time step {time_step}: {sample_predictions[0]:.0f}")
else:
    print(f"No data found for vehicle '{vehicle_id}' at time step {time_step}.")

which gives
Predicted number of cell_ids for vehicle 'veh2312' at time step 2194: 7

